# How to put FloatingActionButton to Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How can I put my `fab` on my fragment? help please I'm getting errors such as.

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment

in my fragment acticity. Well here are my codes.

well the problem is in the    `getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.activity_ownerhome);`

```
#ownerhome.java

public class ownerhome extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ownerhome);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

}
```

## ownerhomeFragment.java

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_owner, container, false);


    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(getActivity()));
    lvCars = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvOnwer);

    pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Log.d(TAG, pref.getString("username", ""));
    Log.d(TAG, pref.getString("password", ""));


    PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(getActivity(), this);
    tvUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvUser);
    tvUser.setText("Hello! "+pref.getString("username", ""));

    taskRead.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/user.php?owner="+pref.getString("username", ""));

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), InsertActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(lvCars);
    return v;
}
```

## content_ownerhome.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.kun.carkila.ownerhome"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_ownerhome">

<fragment
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:name="com.example.kun.carkila.ownerFragment"
android:id="@+id/ownerhomeFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## activity_ownerhome.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.kun.carkila.ownerhome">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_ownerhome" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/plus" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

## fragmentOwnerHome.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.kun.carkila.ownerhome"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_ownerhome">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="450sp"
    android:id="@+id/lvOnwer"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:id="@+id/tvUser" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> STACK TRACE

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.kun.carkila, PID: 9267
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kun.carkila/com.example.kun.carkila.ownerhome}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.example.kun.carkila.ownerFragment.onCreateView(ownerFragment.java:127)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.example.kun.carkila.ownerhome.onCreate(ownerhome.java:12)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #12: Duplicate id 0x7f0e00aa, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.example.kun.carkila.ownerFragment
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2293)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

Comment: could you post your whole stack trace?

Comment: @GlennPorter - post updated sir. Thanks :D

Comment: try changing getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.activity_ownerhome); from your onCreateView of your fragment class,and inflate inflate appropriate layout xml file

Comment: now u r using activity_ownerhome for both activity and fragment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have added the floating action button in your activity_ownerhome.xml and you are initializing it in ownerhomeFragment.java.

So add your FloatingActionButton in fragmentownerhome.xml itself like this

```
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  tools:context="com.example.kun.carkila.ownerhome"
  tools:showIn="@layout/activity_ownerhome">

  <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="450sp"
    android:id="@+id/lvOnwer"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

  <TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:id="@+id/tvUser" />

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/plus" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and remove the FloatingActionButton from your activity_ownerhome.xml file.

Comment: I don't think that that's the problem. Thew problem is with how he inflates the fragment. See my answer above.

Comment: Actually this works. But the fab is on the top left. Not on the bottom.

Comment: It's okay now. Thank you sir!

Comment: Use this in your FloatingActionButton

Comment: android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the crash is because your FAB xml code is in the "Activity layout", it is supposed to be in the "fragment layout" file

This is how i use FAB in a fragment

In my fragment **layout file:**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

In my fragment class file:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

And it works...

**NOTE:**
when i included `android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"`
 the application crashed and gave the error :

```
Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the FAB, it's with how you inflate your view.
Replace this code in the Fragment:

```
View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.activity_ownerhome);
```

With this:

```
var v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.{your fragment xml}, container, false);
```

And remove this:

```
 <fragment
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:name="com.example.kun.carkila.ownerFragment"
android:id="@+id/ownerhomeFragment"/>
```

You should define how you want your fragment xml to look, and then inflate it using the code `inflater.inflate...` and put in your fragment xml there, like I wrote above.

**Update:**
Instead of `<include layout="@layout/content_ownerhome" />` place in this:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame" />
```

Then in your Main Activity write this code:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

And you're supposed to see your fragment, if in the fragment you inflated your fragment xml correctly, as stated above.

Comment: Theres nothing on my activity sir when I removed the xml.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the fragment in your main class something like...

```
public class ownerhome extends AppCompatActivity implement ownerhomeFragment {...
```